How to prevent WP All Export from wrapping XML nodes in CDATA?
I’m using the WP All Export plugin on my WordPress site to export custom XML data, specifically a list of image URLs, each within individual XML nodes. However, WP All Export keeps wrapping the entire output in CDATA, which breaks the XML structure I need.
Current Output
This is what I’m currently getting in the export file:
<photos>
    <![CDATA[
        <image_1>https://example.com/image1.jpg</image_1>
        <image_2>https://example.com/image2.jpg</image_2>
        <image_3>https://example.com/image3.jpg</image_3>
        ...
    ]]>
</photos>

Expected Output
I want the output without the CDATA wrapper, like this:
<photos>
    <image_1>https://example.com/image1.jpg</image_1>
    <image_2>https://example.com/image2.jpg</image_2>
    <image_3>https://example.com/image3.jpg</image_3>
    ...
</photos>

Code I’ve Tried
Here’s the PHP code I’m using to generate the XML nodes. I’ve tried both SimpleXMLElement and DOMDocument, but WP All Export still wraps the result in CDATA:
function export_images_as_nodes($images) {
    if (is_string($images)) {
        $images = explode('|', $images);
    }

    if (empty($images) || !is_array($images)) {
        return '';
    }
    $xml_output = "<photos>\n";
    foreach ($images as $index => $url) {
        $url = trim($url);
        if (!empty($url)) { 
            $node_name = "image_" . ($index + 1);
            $xml_output .= "\t<{$node_name}>{$url}</{$node_name}>\n";
        }
    }
    $xml_output .= "\n";
    return $xml_output;
}


What I’ve Tried
•   SimpleXMLElement: Also results in CDATA wrapping.
•   DOMDocument: As shown in the code above, but still no success.
•   Setting WP All Export to Raw Output: I’ve checked all field options in WP All Export to ensure it’s set to output as raw XML, but it still wraps in CDATA.

Question
How can I prevent WP All Export from wrapping my custom XML output in CDATA? Is there a setting or a workaround to enforce pure XML output in this case?
Additional Notes:

WP All Export doesn’t seem to provide direct control over CDATA for
custom fields.
My export structure requires that each image URL is
output as an XML node rather than within a single CDATA block.


The screenshot below https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/code-snippets/#custom-items-loop-for-woocommerce-orders-exports suggests that there should be an option to globally disable this behavior for all fields? (Although then you might get into trouble, if other parts of your export could contains characters that would require wrapping in CDATA.)

It is possible to disable CDATA wrapping either completely or selectively for certain nodes.
Completely Disable CDATA Tag Wrapping
On the Edit Template page, expand Advanced Options section located just below the field box and select Never wrap data in CDATA tags. Then check the preview or save a template and rerun the export.

However, this option is not recommended, as it can produce an invalid XML file.
Exclude Specific Nodes from CDATA Tag Wrapping
Use the wp_all_export_is_wrap_value_into_cdata filter in your Function Editor (or functions.php). This filter accepts the $element_name parameter and returns a boolean value that determines whether to wrap the content of that element.
function do_not_wrap_images_on_export( $is_wrap_into_cdata, $value, $element_name ) {
    if ( $element_name == 'photos' ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $is_wrap_into_cdata;
}
add_filter( 'wp_all_export_is_wrap_value_into_cdata', 'do_not_wrap_images_on_export', 10, 3 );

After saving the code and template, check the preview and perform an actual export.
